# Using Max and receive error 'sequence contains no elements'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I am adding a row to my table. One of the columns (`SubjectCount`) holds a count value. The count value should get the max value of this column and add 1 to it.

I added this code

```
s.SubjectCount = GetAll().Max(t => t.SubjectCount as int?)?? 0 + 1;
```

but the value is always 1. If i change it to

```
s.SubjectCount = GetAll().Max(t => t.SubjectCount) + 1;
```

Then it works if an existing row is present but not if the table/value is empty i get the error "***sequence contains no elements***".

I searched on the error and have also tried `DefaultIfEmpty()` but that didnt resolve the issue (unless i have my syntax incorrect).

Finally `GetAll()` currently returns no rows (which is where i think the problem is at) so i know i could add the first row manually but ideally i would like a concrete solution to this problem if the tables are empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
s.SubjectCount = GetAll().Max(t => t.SubjectCount as int?)?? 0;
s.SubjectCount++;
```

Your previous implementation does not add 1 if there is one   or more rows in your table, that's why it always returns one.

Comment: How is it different from the first try of the author?

Comment: See the updated answer. I'm pretty sure it's just a case if not adding 1 to the left side of the `??` operator

Answer (score 1):

I think the most safe way is to avoid shortcuts:

```
var entities = GetAll();
s.SubjectCount = (entities?.Any() == true ? entities.Max(t => t.SubjectCount) : 0) + 1;
```

You should also consider performing the Max operation directly in SQL rather than in memory.

Comment: I just saw your answer and i will give it a shot but the first answer i tried did do the trick.